# Installing daemon on a fresh ubuntu system

Tags: linux, daemon

I have done a linux service using the article on this link
http://shahmirj.com/blog/the-initd-script

After that I copied the files into the init.d directory

```
cp -f "myserviced" "/usr/sbin/myserviced"
cp -f "myservice" "/etc/init.d/myservice"
ln -s "/etc/init.d/myservice" "/etc/rc2.d/S99myservice"
ln -s "/etc/init.d/myservice" "/etc/rc0.d/K99myservice"
```

In the next step I started the service using the command
Collapse | Copy Code

```
service myservice start
```

Then it prints like this
myservice: unrecognized service

Why I am getting this error. I am using Ubuntu OS for installing my service. Not installed any chkconfig tool for installing services on linux. How I can solve this without installing any other tools.

Comment: I created my myserviced using C++

Comment: Do you use sudo?

Comment: Also i believe the Init system is phased out in favour of upstart(or in the process of being phased out), not sure of details

Comment: yes I am using sudo

Comment: I cant find the option, but you would be better served taking up this question in Ubuntu or the unix stack exchanges, its rather off topic here.

Comment: OK i will put this on ther too

Comment: is "myservice" executable? (chmod +x myservice) should make that happen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the issue by using a skeleton script on Ubuntu OS

Debian and therefore Ubuntu, supplies a template that uses the Debian start-stop-daemon command to start and stop daemons. It is only necessary to copy this template to a new file of the correct name and modify it for the purpose.

```
sudo cp /etc/init.d/skeleton /etc/init.d/mydaemon
```

My Ubuntu service is working perfect now. Check this article for more details for any others who struggle to create a daemon on Ubuntu OS

http://www.andrewault.net/2010/05/27/creating-a-perl-daemon-in-ubuntu/